# How to set values for datepicker in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a list of datepickers i need to set the value based on selection of first date picker, if we select the value in first date picker same value should be passed to all other date pickers

```
<input name="start"  id='from'  class="date-pick form-control" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
<input name="start" id='to' class="date-pick form-control" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
<input name="start" id='return' class="date-pick form-control" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
 <input name="start" id='depart' class="date-pick form-control" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" />
```

Here is my jquery

```
$('input.date-pick, .input-daterange input[name="start"]').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {

    var date2 = $('.date-pick').datepicker('getDate', '+1d'); 
    //alert (date2);
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 
    $('input.date-pick).datepicker('setDate', date2);
});
```

But its not working.Please help to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please change date2 date 3 date 4 to date1 date1 date1 in the fiddle.

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jt2jq7uz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$("#datepicker1, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4").datepicker();
$("#datepicker1").datepicker("option", "onSelect", function (dateText, inst) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate(inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText, inst.settings);

    var date2 = new Date(date1.getTime());
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker("setDate", date1);

    var date3 = new Date(date1.getTime());
    date3.setDate(date3.getDate() + 2);
    $("#datepicker3").datepicker("setDate", date1);

    var date4 = new Date(date1.getTime());
    date4.setDate(date4.getDate() + 3);
    $("#datepicker4").datepicker("setDate", date1);
});
});
```

[**Link Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/KBq48/)